# combinatorics -- assigning jobs to children when jobs matter

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $10$ jobs to assign to $3$ children. All jobs will get assigned, but not all kids may get a job: it's okay if a kid gets no jobs as long as all $10$ jobs are assigned. However, it is important which kid gets which job.

> Example: In the case where the first person gets $2$ jobs, if they get "cleaning the dishes" and "turning off TV", it is a different case from getting "cleaning the dishes" and "taking out trash". However, "dishes" and "TV" is not a different case from "TV" and "dishes" (order within assignments to $1$ person does not matter).

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: sounds like the kids are getting exploited

Comment: Is the task to count how many ways are there to assign jobs to children? Or do you mean how do you assign jobs?

Comment: Oh sorry, thank you for your question. It is to count the number of ways to assign when who gets the job matters

Answer (score 2):

There are $3$ options for each job and $10$ jobs. The answer is thus $3^{10}$

Comment: Wow, I was thinking in a very complicated way. This actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: happy to help. ${}{}{}$